# css content image placement

Tags: html, css

why doesn't this work ??

CSS

```
.iconM-display {
  content : url('../images/mthc/companyoverview-icon.png');
}
```

HTML... OF THE ENTIRE MENU

```
<div class="mp-pusher" id="mp-pusher">
    <!-- mp-menu -->
    <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
       <div class="mp-level">
          <a href="index.html">
             <h2 class="iconM iconM-world text-center">HOME</h2>
          </a>
          <ul>
             <li class="iconM-display">
                <a class="iconM-display" href="#">What is Music Therapy?</a>
                <div class="mp-level">
                   <h2 ">What is Music Therapy?</h2>
                   <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                   <ul>
                   </ul>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="iconM iconM;arrow-left">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/mthc/contactus-icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" hspace="10">Who Benefits?</a>
                <div class="mp-level">
                   <h2>Who Benefits?</h2>
                   <a href="#">back</a>
                   <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Autism</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">PMLD</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dementia</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Mental Health</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">SEN</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="iconM iconM">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/mthc/contactus-icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" hspace="10">Vignettes/Media</a>
                <div class="mp-level">
                   <h2>Vignettes/Media</h2>
                   <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                   <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Zak</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Geoff</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Jill</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Simon</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="iconM iconM;arrow-left">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/mthc/contactus-icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" hspace="10">Who are Musability?</a>
                <div class="mp-level">
                   <h2>Who are Musability?</h2>
                   <a href="#"><img src="images/mthc/contactus-icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" hspace="10">back</a>
                   <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Local Links</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Supporting Merseyside</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="iconM iconM">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/mthc/contactus-icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" hspace="10">Workshops</a>
                <div class="mp-level">
                   <h2><img src="images/mthc/contactus-icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" hspace="10">Workshops</h2>
                   <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                   <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Schools</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Councils</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Healthcare Professionals</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Social Worker profession</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#"><img src="images/mthc/contactus-icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" hspace="10">Referrals/Contacts</a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><img src="images/mthc/speechbubbles-icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" hspace="10">Testimonials</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /mp-menu -->
```

the question refers to the first li where I have defined iconM-display as per the css ... very strange I am obviously missing something basic no doubt any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please make a jsfiddle. It helps solving the problem greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only just noticed. But you are trying to assign `{content:""}` on a non-pseudo selector.

https://css-tricks.com/css-content/

> CSS has a property called content. It can only be used with the pseudo
>   elements :after and :before. It is written like a pseudo selector
>   (with the colon), but it's called a pseudo element because it's not
>   actually selecting anything that exists on the page but adding
>   something new to the page.

Comment: yes that is correct... i have posted the answer below thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

you basically have to have either ::before or ::after once you have typed content.... worked perfectly for me

Comment: yikes. Not sure how this happened, it was in error. I have removed the close vote :)